# creating a list of dataframes from list of lists of dataframes in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of list of dataframes

`list = {[df1],[df1,df2],[df1,df2,df3]}`
that I want to concatenate the dataframes in one list to one dataframe, ultimately resulting in a list of dataframes.

what I want:

```
list1 = [df_a, df_b, df_c]
```

where

```
df_a = df1, 
df_b = df1 + df2, 
df_c = df1 + df2 +df3
```

I tried

```
list1=[]
for n in list:
    list1.append(pd.concat([list[n]]))
```

but it raised error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list`

how can I achieve list1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created the 3 sample pandas data-frames for your questions solution

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [1, 2, 3], 'colors': ['red', 'white', 'blue']})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [4, 5, 6], 'colors': ['Orange', 'Green', 'White']})
df3=pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [7, 8, 9], 'colors': ['black', 'yellow', 'Purple']})

# Define the list of lists of dataframes
list_of_lists = [[df1], [df1, df2], [df1, df2, df3]]
# Initialize an empty list to hold the concatenated dataframes
concatenated_list = []

# Loop through the list of lists of dataframes
for df_list in list_of_lists:
   concatenated_df = pd.concat(df_list)
   concatenated_list.append(concatenated_df)
# Print the list of concatenated dataframes
print(concatenated_list)
```

In case if it solves your problem please accept this as an Answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pandas.concat()` function for this purpose

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```